# Change application titlebar size?

Tags: 23.04

After upgrading to ubuntu 23.04, the titlebar of every application (that usually contains only the application name) got very big. It's even bigger now than the buttom taskbar!

Question: how can I change the size of the titlebar header?

The file manager nautilus does not have a title bar. But the bar from other applications like evolution, kate, terminal are all bigger than normal. Scale is set to 1.0 GPU driver is metapackage nvidia-driver-525

Comment: Also the title bar of, say, the file manager? Do you have scaling enabled? What is your resolution and graphics card?

Comment: The file manager nautilus does not have a title bar. But the bar from other applications like evolution, kate, terminal are all bigger than normal. Scale is set to 1.0 GPU driver is metapackage nvidia-driver-525

Comment: It will be good to add that information to the question: it will make the problem sharper.